# jQuery on submit validation, with modal dialog at the end?

Tags: jquery, validation, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form at the moment I'd like to validate, and assuming everything is correct, I'd like it to then popup a dialog confirming their details, here's an example of the code I have so far:

```
var userConfirmed = false;

$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            userConfirmed = true;
            $("#inputform").submit();
        },
        "No, I'll change them.": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

// check they've submitted what they need to
$("form").submit(function() {

    // lots of these
    if (something) {
        return false;
    }

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    return userConfirmed;

});
```

The initial validation works fine - it checks against the criteria and flags up as appropiate, and if none of that criteria is met, it'll display the modal box just as I want. So far, so good.

The problem however is when I press 'yes' to submit the form, it doesn't submit, until you press the actual 'submit' button again, argh! Any call to submit the forum using jQuery fails.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thank you.

Comment: I've tried stripping back _all_ of my code apart from this - http://pastebin.com/iUARx8CM - still no joy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a flag somewhere telling whether or not the dialog already appeared, and the user clicked yes. Example:

```
var userConfirmed = false;
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    if ( userConfirmed ) {
        userConfirmed = false; // Reset it to false
        return true; // No need to validate anything, that was already done last time
    }
    var form = $(this);
    // ...
        "Yes": function() {
            userConfirmed = true; // Confirm that the dialog was shown and the user clicked "Yes"
            $(this).dialog("close");
            form.submit(); // Try again; this time, the validation was already done
        },
    // ...
    return false; // Don't submit; the user haven't confirmed the info on the dialog
});
```

Without that flag, you'd be in a chicken-and-egg situation: the submit opens the dialog, and the dialog calling `$("form").submit()` opens the dialog again...

If you have many forms and don't want to use a "global" var, you can use `data` for the same purpose.

**Update:** live example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/ZEEaL/). Tested with success in Chrome and Firefox (it will display a blank page 3 seconds after submitting).

Comment: This is a good idea, thank you. My main concern is if the dialog is presented to the user and they edit their data, it then wouldn't appear again with a final prompt before they submit. I know that sounds like sucky design, but it's a requirement unfortunately :$

Comment: Damn, ignore me - sorry I only just realised your dialogAppeared flag is set _only_ when the user clicks yes. :-)

Comment: You mean, if the user chose "Cancel"? That way, `dialogAppeared` wouldn't be set to true (note that only the "Yes" button sets it). Maybe I should have used a better name for that var... [done]

Comment: How very bizarre, when it finally tries to submit the form with return true; nothing happens. It stops the validation process as it should, but doesn't submit the form until I manually press the button again? :/

Comment: Changed the final return false; to return userConfirmed; - seemed like a good idea at the time, but still doesn't work

Comment: That's weird... Unfortunatly I can't help you with that. But the updated answer from remibreton+PCasagrande looks promising, I'd say even cleaner than mine, you could try that instead

Comment: Added a live example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/ZEEaL/) and it worked fine. My bet is that some exception were thrown in your "Yes" button that you didn't notice, that's why it only worked after clicking the button again (the variable was still true at that point)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the dialog opens does not stop the execution of the code. `valToReturn` is returned by `$("form").submit()` before it's even set.

You could do something like this:

```
//Save the default behavior to break any loops
var defaultSubmit = $.extend(true, {}, $("form").submit);

$("form").submit(function(e) {

    var valToReturn = true;

    // lots of these
    if (something) {
        return false;
    }

    // popup the dialog confirmation
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                defaultSubmit(); // User confirmed, submit form.
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close"); // Form already prevented from submitting. Exit quietly.
            }
        }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    return false; // Prevent form from being submitted

});
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the update :) This is a nice idea, I tried it just before posting but unfortunately it causes an infinite loop of constantly trying to call the form.submit function

Comment: Try saving the existing `$("form").submit()` into a variable and then change the functionality with jQuery. In your OK function you could just then call the saved version and the form would process properly.

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately it still results in an infinite loop

Comment: I like the general idea of saving the last handler, but will this code really do it? From what I could read, it will save `$.fn.submit` in a var, then call it without any `this`, I don't think that would work at all. Even if you used `$.proxy` to bind it to the right element, it would still be the same function, so the custom handler would be called again.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately it seems like the defaultSubmit() function call on the 'Ok' button press simply runs the submit function again, popping up the dialog :( I've updated my initial post, feel like progress is being made but blah

Comment: I submitted a change; I forgot javascript updates variables like that. The solution is use `var defaultSubmit = $.extend(true, {}, $("form").submit);` What this does is save a copy, not a reference to the full thing, into an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

as always I recommend the use [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for validation then code would look like this

```
$("#formid").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
               $("#dialog").dialog({
     buttons: {
         "Ok": function() {
             form.submit();
             $(this).dialog("close");
         },
         "Cancel": function() {
             $(this).dialog("close");
         }
     }
});
    }
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/B4Q3D/1/)

Comment: Many thanks, I wanted to avoid an external plugin if possible but looks like I should probably check this one out

Comment: it is worth noting that this plugin was build by a member of the jQuery team and is widely used to validate forms and will save you tons of time writing code

Comment: Just tried to implement this, it's very good (thank you) but it's massively inconsistent with the way errors are generated across the site at present (using jGrowl calls and focusing on the element with the error) and as a result would take a ridiculously large amount of time to implement :( Thank you though, it's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would attach the event to a button instead of the form. Just attach it to a submit button click. Then you can use `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from submitting until the dialogue has been confirmed. In the 'Yes' function just put `$('form').submit()`. No need to worry about the return value that way either.

Comment: Thank you, I did consider this, but it'd make it awkward when a user submits a form simply by hitting the enter key.